# getty service on RP3 just doesn't go away

Tags: services

I have put a neo GPS chip onto the `/dev/ttyAMA0` port and set it up.

All is good until I reboot the pi then I have comms issues with the AMA0 port. I eventually find a service I thought was dead and gone to be back and active, causing this grief.

Before I reboot I have this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/lx200 $ systemctl -a|grep getty

serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service                                                                          loaded    inactive dead      Serial Getty on ttyAMA0
```

and after I reboot:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl -a|grep getty

serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service                                                                            loaded    active   running   Serial Getty on ttyAMA0
```

To disable it I entered the following commands:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/lx200 $ sudo systemctl stop  serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service 

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

and to remove it I entered:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service remove
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this zombie?

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment but I don't have enough rep to add comments yet.

Have you removed "console=serial0,115200" from /boot/cmdline.txt ?